# How to extract everything between <table> and </table> in multiple HTML files

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have been trying to extract this data for a couple of hours without luck.
I either want to just extract all the table tags from the HTML and save them to a separate file or everything between these tags.  I am trying to do it with Notepad++.

I got this to select it:

```
<table\b[^>]*>(.*?)</table>$
```

but if I bookmark it, it only bookmarks the first line. Plus, I cannot do it for too many files at once.

Could you please advise?  Should I download another reg exp application?

Comment: Welcome on superuser. Please try to format your code and use the preview feature to see whether it really looks as expecetd.

Comment: Regex really doesn't work for html.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

[Scraper Wiki](https://scraperwiki.com) has a tool to extract data from tables in websites.